# ASP.net IF Request.Url.Host == Wildcard

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I use a wildcard in the URL of my comparison for Request.URL.Host? I have a site that's been running for years with the test site showing as blue. The comparison used to use the entire URL.

```
    @if (Request.Url.Host == "URLtest.site.com") //
    {
    bodyclass = "test";
    }
```

We are adding a second test site and I'd like to set this one time. So I would like to use a wildcard. Something like this, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

```
@if (Request.Url.Host == "*test.*") //
{
    bodyclass = "test";
}
```

Comment: I believe you should use a regex for that comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx as suggested in other answers.

A simpler check would be to use string.Contains()

```
@if (Request.Url.Host.Contains("test.")) //
{
    bodyclass = "test";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I started down this path but wasn't sure how to set the if statement using contains. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Regex Match method

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


var pattern = @"\w*test.\w*";
string input = "url2test.site.com";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match .Success)
{
}
```